# Initial Value in TextFormField not being initialized

Tags: android, flutter, forms, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to populate my form with data fetched from Firestore, for which I am using the initialvalue method. But for some reason, the value isn't displayed even though it has been passed to the method correctly. If I pass a direct text like 'Hello', it shows that but not when I give it thorough an object say widget.data.text. I have tried using textcontroller as well but face same issue with that.

This is the code for one of my fields.

```
class NameField1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const NameField1({super.key, this.validator, this.fnode, this.nfocusnode, this.onChanged, this.data});

  final FormFieldValidator<String?>? validator;
  final FocusNode? fnode;
  final ReferalData? data;
  final FocusNode? nfocusnode;
  final ValueChanged<String>? onChanged;

  @override
  State<NameField1> createState() => _NameField1State();
}

class _NameField1State extends State<NameField1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      style: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 22,
      ),
      autocorrect: false,
      initialValue: widget.data?.Company,
      // controller: widget.tCont,
      enableSuggestions: false,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        border: InputBorder.none,
        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
        hintText: 'Name',
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 22,
        ),
      ),
      focusNode: widget.fnode,
      onFieldSubmitted: (_) => widget.nfocusnode!.requestFocus(),
      validator: widget.validator,
      onChanged: widget.onChanged,
    );
  }
}
```

The Referal Data is obtained asynchronously from a StreamBuilder.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Your data from the stream can be passed to the method correctly, but not at the moment your `TextFormField` is initialized.

I suppose that currently it works like that:

1. Your `_NameField1State` is initialized - there is no data in `widget.data`, so it displays nothing;
2. Your `StreamBuilder` pushes data to `NameField1` widget and you can see it.

You can check whether that's the case by adding `initialData` to your `StreamBuilder`.

Comment: You are right, the initialdata value is being showed up now, in the text field. This value is present when the connectionstate is 'waiting', when the connectionstate is active the value changes to the one that is fetched from the server. But the textfield remains unchanged. Any ideas as to what can be done here?

Comment: @AnuragHale to change textField you need to add `setState` to your `_NameField1State` widget. At the moment your stream will fetch the data and push it your whole widget will be rebuilt, causing `initialValue` to update.

Comment: Can you explain how to implement that setState? I cant seem to get it